# Opensearch use Bulk to reload the document with same _id

Tags: opensearch

I plan to use the `bulk` service to load the documents into opensearch, and i am custom create the `_id`, but in some case the job failed or whatever, i need to redo the job, so this means for some document i need to load twice. can i use the _id to avoid duplication? and if this could help avoid duplicate, is opensearch using versioning to save both version or just remove the old one?

Thanks

Comment: How are you creating the custom `_id` values?